# How to regex a phrase up to a parenthesis?

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm trying to regex a group called reason, i have got very close but can't quite figure out the last part. I want to regex everything between `Reason:` up to and not including the first bracket in `(winRc=999)`

The string that is being extracted is below.

Reason: The user name or password is incorrect. (winRc=999)

I wish to have an expression that shows:

A Full Match of "Reason: The user name or password is incorrect."
A Group 'Reason' Match of "The user name or password is incorrect."

Comment: Did you try ```'^(Reason.*) \('```?

Comment: You can use `^Reason[^(]+`

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something similar to what @CodeManiac was mentioning above

```
/Reason: ([^(]*)/
```

A demo from regex101

https://regex101.com/r/J2ddFQ/1

The takes advantage of using a negative character class, very powerful.